# Flex xml lost on debug

Tags: xml, apache-flex, debugging

When I start debugging a Flex project, I have a error because some xml aren't find, so i copy manualy all the files from the project (/src) to (/bin-debug).

This happen to some xml files no every single file.

Any idea what can happening with this files?

Answer (score 0):

There is an option "Copy non-embedded resources" that you can check in the compiler settings. This is probably what you are after.

Comment: I found a check box name "Copy non-embedded files to output folder" that is checked. (but doesn't solve the problem)

Comment: That's strange. Are those XML files in a folder that is set as a source folder? I see that you said they are in "src", but just to make sure. If that's not working, try to do a project->clean.

Comment: Finally I make a script that copy the xml, thank you Christophe